# Combine - UITableView.isEditing property publisher doesn't trigger when value changed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, combine

I have a `UITableView` that can go into edit mode by calling this method:

```swift
tableView.setEditing(!tableView.isEditing, animated: true)
```

Now I want to observe the editing state of the tableView to update the text of a bar button item:

```swift
tableView.publisher(for: \.isEditing).sink { [weak self] (isEditing) in
    self?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit"
}.store(in: &disposeBag)
```

However, the publisher doesn't react to the changes to `tableView.isEditing`. Any idea why? It does fire upon initialization of `tableView`.